# How to read a xlsx file with 35 sheets and convert it to a data frame with three dimensions: latitude, longitude and sheet of the xlsx file

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

Im having trouble by converting my xlsx file to a data frame.
First: I do not know how to set the first column as rownames and the first row as col.names (because the first column are latitude values and the first row are longitude values). But THE MAIN issue is that I want each sheet of the xlsx to be part of the third dimension.
I want the dimension of my data frame to be c(length(latitude),length(longitud),35) becaused I got an xlsx with 35 sheets.
How could I do that?

I used this code to get my xlsx file. It worked but when I try to convert it to a data frame called CCSM4 it failed. It has more than 10.000 columns and latitude and longitude are values of my dataframe instead of being just col and rownames.

```
lst <- lapply(1:35, function(i) read_excel("CCSM4-MATRIZ.xlsx", sheet = i))
CCSM4<-as.data.frame(lst)
```

This is how ONE sheet of my xlsx looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hey. Please provide a reproducible example for us to help you. I.e. provide an example Excel file and specify which packages you are using.

Comment: Appears you have "wide data" that you want in "long format". What are the data points inside those sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Data frames (special class of `list` type) only maintains two dimensions. However, R's array (where at 2-D is equivalent to matrix) can have N-dimensions. Hence, consider converting your data frame to matrix and with `sapply` (wrapper to `lapply`) can convert to three-dimensional array.

```
lat_lon-array <- sapply(1:35, function(i)
     matrix(read_excel("CCSM4-MATRIZ.xlsx", sheet = i)),
     simplify = "array")

dim(lat_lon-array)
```